# Finding the nVIDIA Toolkit Extensions library with CMake

Tags: cmake, cuda, nvtx

I'm using CMake 3.13, with inherent support for CUDA as a language, to build a project. This project requires the nVIDIA Toolkit Extensions library. On a previous system, I had it under `/usr/local/cuda/lib64`. I used a `find_library()` command which I thought should be sufficient, and all was well. But - it isn't, and it wasn't: On a system in which CUDA is installed using OS distribution packages, under /usr directly, my command doesn't work.

To be more specific, I'm using:

```
find_library(CUDA_NVTX_LIBRARY
  NAMES nvToolsExt nvTools nvtoolsext nvtools nvtx NVTX
  PATHS ${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR} ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  PATH_SUFFIXES "lib64" "common/lib64" "common/lib" "lib"
  DOC "Location of the CUDA Toolkit Extension (NVTX) library"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

and this is missing `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnvToolsExt.so`.

Questions:

- How should I alter my find_library command not to miss such target-platform-specific folders?
- Am I looking for the NVTX library the wrong way? Can I somehow rely on what CMake finds internally instead?

Notes:

- I have basically the same issue with `libOpenCL.so`, nVIDIA's OpenCL layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer regards CMake versions earlier than 3.17; you should really switch to a newer version of CMake, which makes your life much easier.)

CMake does figure out the paths of a lot of other CUDA-related libraries, e.g.:

```
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart.so
CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so
CUDA_cudadevrt_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudadevrt.a
CUDA_cudart_static_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcudart_static.a
CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcufft.so
CUDA_cupti_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcupti.so
CUDA_curand_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurand.so
CUDA_cusolver_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcusolver.so
CUDA_cusparse_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcusparse.so
CUDA_nppc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppc.so
CUDA_nppial_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppial.so
CUDA_nppicc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppicc.so
CUDA_nppicom_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppicom.so
CUDA_nppidei_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppidei.so
CUDA_nppif_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppif.so
CUDA_nppig_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppig.so
CUDA_nppim_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppim.so
CUDA_nppist_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppist.so
CUDA_nppisu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppisu.so
CUDA_nppitc_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnppitc.so
CUDA_npps_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnpps.so
CUDA_rt_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so
```

I think it's [actually a bug](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19386) that it doesn't do so for the NVTX and OpenCL libraries. Still, we can take the paths it finds for other libraries - perhaps the main one, `CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY`, and use it as a search hint.

The result is even uglier than what I had before, but it does seems to work:

```
get_filename_component(CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY_DIR "${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY}" PATH CACHE)

find_library(CUDA_OPENCL_LIBRARY
  NAMES OpenCL opencl
  PATHS "${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY_DIR}" "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}" ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  PATH_SUFFIXES "lib64" "lib"
  DOC "Location of the CUDA OpenCL support library"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

find_library(CUDA_NVTX_LIBRARY
  NAMES nvToolsExt nvTools nvtoolsext nvtools nvtx NVTX
  PATHS "${CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY_DIR}" "${CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR}" ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  PATH_SUFFIXES "lib64" "common/lib64" "common/lib" "lib"
  DOC "Location of the CUDA Toolkit Extension (NVTX) library"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try `CMAKE_CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES` (suggested [here](https://shawnliu.me/post/cuda-as-a-language-in-cmake/)), which worked for me:

```
project(theproject LANGUAGES CUDA)
find_library(LIBNVTOOLSEXT nvToolsExt PATHS ${CMAKE_CUDA_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES})
```